# How does the asymptotic metric fluctuation in $n \to m$ scattering relates to the soft factor in Weinberg's soft graviton theorem?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, scattering, quantum-gravity, asymptotics

I'm reading arXiv: [1411.5745 [hep-th]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5745). In Sec. 5, the authors show how the memory effect and Weinberg's soft graviton theorem are two faces of the same coin. I'm interested in understanding a specific statement used in the paper. Let me recollect some statements and establish notation in order to ask my question.

Consider an $n \to m$ scattering process in a theory that includes quantum gravity (at least on an effective level). We denote by $\mathcal{A}_{m+n}(p_1,\ldots,p_n;p'_1,\ldots,p'_m)$ the scattering amplitude for this process. Weinberg's soft graviton theorem states that the amplitude for the $n \to m + 1$ scattering that corresponds to the previous scattering plus the emission of a soft photon is such that

$$\lim_{\omega \to 0} \mathcal{A}_{m+n+1}(p_1,\ldots,p_n;p'_1,\ldots,p'_m,(\omega k, \epsilon_{\mu\nu})) = \sqrt{8\pi G} S_{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu} \mathcal{A}_{m+n}(p_1,\ldots,p_n;p'_1,\ldots,p'_m) + \mathcal{O}(\omega^0),$$

where $\omega k$ is the four-momentum of the soft graviton and $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ is its polarization tensor. This is eq. (5.1) on the paper mentioned above. The specific form of the so-called soft factor $S_{\mu\nu}$ seems irrelevant to my question.

The authors then discuss the memory effect and eventually get to the following statement:

> Next we note that to linear order, the expectation value of the asymptotic metric
> fluctuation produced in the process of $n \to m$ scattering obeys
> $$\lim_{\omega \to 0} \omega h^{TT}_{\mu\nu}(\omega,k)\epsilon^{\mu\nu} = \lim_{\omega\to0} \frac{\omega \mathcal{A}_{m+n+1}(p_1,\ldots,p_n;p'_1,\ldots,p'_m,(\omega k, \epsilon_{\mu\nu}))}{\mathcal{A}_{m+n}(p_1,\ldots,p_n;p'_1,\ldots,p'_m)}$$

My question is: why is this last formula valid? How does one know that this ratio of amplitudes yields precisely the metric fluctuation due to the scattering process?

Comment: Did you not go through the formulas (5.3) -- (5.5)?

Comment: @Prahar I did, but they seem to follow from considerations of the memory effect, while the expressions above follow from the soft theorem. I don't see how those equations answer my question

Comment: I do see why there is an interest in $\omega h_{\mu\nu}^{TT}$